# Not supported in android api level less than 24

Tags: java, android

I'm getting following errors! what would be the reason

```
Information:Gradle tasks [:app:generateDebugSources, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:mockableAndroidJar, :app:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies, :app:compileDebugSources, :app:compileDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:compileDebugUnitTestSources]
Error:Collection.java:47-48: Default method java.util.stream.Stream stream() not supported in Android API level less than 24
Error:Collection.java:41-42: Default method boolean removeIf(java.util.function.Predicate filter) not supported in Android API level less than 24
Error:AnnotatedElement.java:30-31: Default method boolean isAnnotationPresent(java.lang.Class annotationClass) not supported in Android API level less than 24
```

There are about 80 errors and all of them are ends with not supported in android api level less than 24. I changed the api level to 25 as well still it did not fix the issue can someone help me with this issue?

Comment: what is your minSDKVersion?

Comment: 23 but when i change it to 24 and 25 too the errors are same

Comment: and what is CompileSDKVersion? do you change that too to 24 or 25?

Comment: yeah that was always 25

Comment: Are you making use of any external library?

Comment: yeah i imported them

Comment: you have to make sure that your included library if does have its own build file, that also declares higher minSDK and CompileSDK and TargetSDK versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the use of `java.util.stream.Stream` is not supported below API 24

for device not running that you need to do a check

```
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.N){

}else{

}
```

Comment: hi thanks but what should be inside that if condition? Sorry i'm just a beginner.

Comment: < 24 use something else else use `Stream`